# Remove space from columns while importing in SAS

Tags: csv, sas

I have a CSV file which i want to import in SAS but the column name of CSV have blank space. For example one of the column is 'country code'. I want to remove remove space and put '_' in that place so that column name becomes Country_Code. Any help..how i can do it using SAS Code.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a CSV (comma delimited), then you shouldn't have any problems here.  `PROC IMPORT` ought to import the file and change the name for you.  It will *label* the variable including the space, but it should make the change.  (Verify this in SAS Display Manager by opening the dataset and selecting View-> Column Names).

If it's not, then you might try (before the proc) adding `options validvarname=v7;`.  If the setting is currently `any`, then technically the name with the space is a valid name; it may pass `PROC IMPORT`'s checks.  If you're using Enterprise Guide, this setting is `any` by default.

Comment: but i want to change the column name to country_code...is there any way to rename column  name?

Comment: Column name = variable name.  If you want to change the variable *label* to country_code, just use a `label` statement in `proc datasets` or a later data step.